# Use of Provider inside Interceptor

Tags: flutter

Following is my Interceptor

```
class LoggingInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  @override
  void onRequest(
      RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    //BuildContext c = Container() as BuildContext;
    Provider.of<LoadingState>(context).startLoader();
    return handler.next(options);
  }

  @override
  void onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    Provider.of<LoadingState>(context).stopLoader();
    handler.next(response);
  }
}
```

I want to use provider in request and response , as in interceptor context is not available, is there any way or alternative to this.

**Provider.of(context).startLoader(); and
Provider.of(context).stopLoader();**

Comment: Use Consumer instead of Provider.of(context) if you don't need Provider.of(context, listen:true). See https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html

Comment: It required builder and to create I need widget. I do not required widget in interceptor